# The production of cosmic jets

Tags: electromagnetism, astrophysics, magnetohydrodynamics, relativistic-jets

For cosmic jets produced in gamma ray bursts or quasars, I've read that you have to assume a "Force-free magnetosphere" in order to explain these phenomena through electromagnetism. From my understanding, force-free means that the particles from the accretion disk have velocity along the lines of the magnetic field, but my question is how did the particles get velocity in that direction in the first place?

Comment: As a general rule good tagging is very helpful in bringing in users who can answer a question well.

Answer (score 0):

Gravity is the cause of the velocity and if too much matter spirals inward at one time the excess is ejected outwards at the poles with a very high velocity. You also see this with what's called active galaxies.